# Expand rows in pandas dataframe with date range in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to expand a pandas dataframe with one row for each date between a date range in two columns.

For example, given the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3],
                        'start': [pd.Timestamp('2023-9-15'), pd.Timestamp('2023-8-7'), pd.Timestamp('2023-10-12')],
                        'end': [pd.Timestamp('2023-9-18'), pd.Timestamp('2023-8-12'), pd.Timestamp('2023-10-15')]})

In[15]: df
Out[15]:
   id      start        end
0   1 2023-09-15 2023-09-18
1   2 2023-08-07 2023-08-12
2   3 2023-10-12 2023-10-15
```

I would like to produce the following dataframe:

```
Out[23]:
    id       date
0    1 2023-09-15
1    1 2023-09-16
2    1 2023-09-17
3    1 2023-09-18
4    2 2023-08-07
5    2 2023-08-08
6    2 2023-08-09
7    2 2023-08-10
8    2 2023-08-11
9    2 2023-08-12
10   3 2023-10-12
11   3 2023-10-13
12   3 2023-10-14
13   3 2023-10-15
```

I can do it using the following code:

```py
def _expand_dates(r: pd.Series):
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=r.start, end=r.end)
    r = pd.DataFrame([r] * len(date_range))
    r['date'] = date_range

    return r

expanded = df.apply(_expand_dates, axis=1)
df = pd.concat(expanded.to_list(), ignore_index=True)
```

but when the number of rows in the input dataframe is large (100k+), the operation becomes very slow.

Is there a better way?